# Listing Directories on terminal with Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to write a perl one liner for listing the content of a directory like with the "ls -l" Unix command however I only want to output directories and not files

I have managed to do it using a perl script but I want to try and see if it can be reduced to a single line using a pipe like

```
ls -l | grep "something"
```

or

```
ls -l | perl -...
```

the way I have done it so far is this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(LS_D, "ls -l |");

while(<LS_D>) {
  print if /^d.*/; #print line if line starts with d
}
```

Also could you tell me why this works with the pipe in "ls -l |" but not with "ls -l"?

Thanks

Comment: The `ls -ld */` gives you the long listing of only directories, no need for Perl.  Is that what you need?  As for `|`, you are opening a process there and the pipe signifies whether you write to it (`"| command"`) or read from it (`"command |"`).  See [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Comment: In a Perl one-liner: `perl -we'print grep { /^d/ } qx(ls -l)'`

Comment: "A Perl one-liner that behaves the same as `ls -l`..." So, uhh, what's wrong with just using `ls -l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long listing of directories can be directly obtained with

```
ls -ld */
```

without a need to filter the output.

As for the `|`, that is how you tell [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to open a process and replace its `STDIN` or `STDOUT`

> For three or more arguments if MODE is `|-`, the filename is interpreted as a command to which output is to be piped, and if MODE is `-|`, the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us. In the two-argument (and one-argument) form, one should replace dash (`-`) with the command. See [Using open() for IPC in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC) for more examples of this.

Without `|`, so with `open(LS_D, "ls -l")`, you are trying to open a *file*, with the name `'ls -l'`

The three-argument `open`, which is recommended with its lexical filehandle, would be

```
open my $read_fh, '-|', 'ls', '-l';
```

where the command with arguments is supplied as a list.

Finally, what you have in your Perl script can be done with a one-liner for example as

```
perl -we'print grep { /^d/ } `ls -l`'
```

but, as shown above, you can get that directly with `ls` on the command line.

---

I should add

- Always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your programs
- Always check calls like `open` and you'll know about, and see the reason for, the failure

  ```
  open my $fh ...  or die "Can't open ... : $!";
  ```

  See [Error Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) for `$!`

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to get my head around bits of Perl, what does the curly braces around the regex do in the one-liner?

Comment: @W22  It's syntax for `grep`: `my @result = grep { code } LIST;`, where `code` runs on each item from (input) `LIST`. Those elements for which it evaluates to true are passed.  It's a filter.  Inside the block `{ }` each element is available as `$_`, the default variable for many things.  So above is `grep { $_ =~ /^d/ } LIST` and if an element is matched the regex returns true.  You may omit `$_ =~` since regex also defaults to matching `$_`. The input here is a list of lines returned by `qx(ls -l)` (`qx` is an operator for backticks, which I always forget how to enter in these comments).

Comment: @W22  Documentation: [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [General Variables in perlvar (for `$_`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

Comment: @W22  Examples. (1) Have an array with numbers and you want only positive ones: `my @pos = grep { $_ > 0 } @nums;`  (2) Have a list of words, and you want only those which are made up strictly of digits: `my @nums = grep { /^\d+$/ } @words;` (3) Have a list, filter out `undef`s `my @good = grep { defined } @ary;` (again, `defined` by default uses `$_`, so it's the same as `{ defined $_ }`) (4) Filter out elements which are empty strings or only spaces `my @nonempty = grep { /\S/ } @ary;` (so each elem has at least one non-space, `\S`) // This is a very random scoop..

Comment: @W22  I also added a note at the end, please have a look